# how to passing coredatastack from AppDelegate to the view controller without navigation controller

Tags: swift, core-data

I know the way to pass coreDataStack to the viewController with navigation controller embedded by this way.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let navigationController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let viewController = navigationController.topViewController as! ViewController

    viewController.coreDataStack = coreDataStack
    return true
}
```

I want to pass the coreDataStack to my viewController without the navigation controller,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as! Home
    viewController.coreDataStack = coreDataStack

    return true
}
```

However, the coreDataStack in the viewController found to be nil.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is creating a new instance of the view controller, not referencing the existing instance.  You should be able to use this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let viewController = window!.rootViewController as! ViewController
    viewController.coreDataStack = coreDataStack
    return true
}
```